# Saving ggplot with R on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ggplot2

I am having issues with saving a ggplot generated graph after install R from source on Ubuntu 10.04.

For instance the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
head(diamonds)
p <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, colour = cut)) + layer(geom = "point")
p <- p + layer(geom = "point")
ggsave("plot.svg")
```

Results in:

```
Saving 7 x 7 in image
Warning messages:
1: In grDevices::svg(...) : unable to load shared object 
  '/app/vendor/R/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
    libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2: In grDevices::svg(...) : failed to load cairo DLL
```

cairo.so is present at: /app/vendor/R/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs/cairo.so

libpng15.so.15 is present at: /app/vendor/libpng/lib/libpng15.so.15

Running capabilities() yields:

```
> capabilities()
jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets
TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo
  TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what may be going wrong here, maybe it is something to do with the location of my libpng15.so.15 file?

Comment: Are you on 10.04 desktop or 10.04 server edition?

Comment: Check if `libpng` is present in an environmental variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If not, you may either reinstall `libpng` or create a symbolic link `ln -s /path/to/libpng /usr/lib`.